# Alternative to tabs in long list?

Tags: design, information, architecture

I've been asked to build a page that lists 6 features.
- 2 of these features are bundled : basic + premium (they are managed on separate Apps)
- 4 features can be purchased separately.
- All features must display on the page

I was thinking to have a tabbed experience for those two features but it doesn't make sense to only tab half the page.

[image: Quick mockup of what I mean]

Comment: I agree it seems initially like a poor idea to have a tabbed section within a larger list, but we might need a bit more context to properly guide you on this one...

Comment: They are features for a wireless plan.  An authorized user would see a dashboard of features. The features are managed by a 3rd party vendor, but each user will have the ability to add the feature, remove it or in some cases upgrade them. (this is the rule for ALL the features)  For 4 features, we will not be able to pull content for the user to display, so only provide the feature name, brief description and ability to remove, add, upgrade. for the 2 bundled features, we can display content but not much.

Comment: They will also have the ability to add/remove and upgrade but with upgrade - they have to upgrade as one (because they're bundled)

Comment: Quick recommendation. You're going to get more attention and better answers with a) a better question and b) a visual of where you're at right now. "Building a strange ask" is essentially meaningless. Normally I'd just edit your question, but I don't really have a strong enough idea of your problem. If you used the built in wireframing tool to show your tabs idea, even if you know it's not right, others will have something to hang your descriptions on, and will find it easier to come up with something that does work.

Comment: Thanks - added a quick mockup of what i mean. It's a strange ask to only bundle 2 features with the rest remaining a la carte.

Answer (score 1):

#### Just show everything

For me, the key line in your question is: "All features must be displayed on the page".

Why not just show them all? Your screen is going to get long, but you could offset that with a filter/menu at the top, as I've included below.

You'll note that I've repeated the numbering (1 and 2) for the bundles and referred to Features X & Y, which it simply to point out that this could get confusing and is something you should pay attention to.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe65sk.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I think you're question is; why show them all? business wants a one stop shop page. It doesn't make the best sense because of how much data they want to show in the bundled features. I can use your design but lay it out in 3 tabs of Basic bundle, premium bundle and standalone features.